# Length mismatch error when using summary_col function of Statsmodels

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, statsmodels

I am using the `summary_col()` function to aggregate multiple OLS regression results instances, the function worked before but keep returning `'ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 6 elements'` recently.

Original code:
Eight OLS regression result instances have been saved into variables...

```
result_list = [mod1_result,mod2_result,mod3_result,mod4_result,mod5_result,mod6_result,\
mod7_result,mod8_result]

name_list = ['reg1','reg2','reg3','reg4','reg5','reg6','reg7','reg8']

info_dict={'Obs':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),\
       'R-squared':lambda x: "{:.3f}".format(x.rsquared)}


regs_table = summary_col(results=result_list, float_format='%0.3f',\
                       stars=True, model_names=name_list, info_dict = info_dict)
```

Any idea to fix the error would be very appreciated!

For simplicity:
Have tried fit 2 simple OLS and aggregate its regression results, which has returned same Error Message

```
Y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,20,100]
X1 = range(1,10)
X1 = sm.add_constant(X1)
results1 = sm.OLS(Y,X1).fit()

Y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,20,100]
X2 = range(10,19)
X2 = sm.add_constant(X2)
results2 = sm.OLS(Y,X2).fit()


print(results1.summary())
print(results2.summary())


table = summary_col([results1,results2])
```

Error I got:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Comment: Just copied pasted your 2nd code example - seems to be working for me (don't get the error - not sure of the output). What version of python and statsmodel are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.4 and Statsmodels 0.9.0

Comment: The function worked once the statsmodels upgraded to the latest version, many thanks!

Comment: Would be great if you can let everyone know for what version it was not working

Comment: I don't think this should work. It does not really make sense in general to create the parameter lists without parameter names for the pandas index.

Comment: The version 0.9.0 was not working.